# Custom Listview onClick not moving to Tab Fragments page

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an activity with CustomAdapter `ListView` and `TabLayout` with three tabs TrainerTab1, TrainerTab2, TrainerTab3. While clicking on an item it should move to next page that is to TrainerTab1 `Fragment`.

I need to pass the id from `ListView` `onClick()` to fragment page. I have used `Bundle` to pass value but the items are not working. When I click on an item it's not responding and not showing any error.

My custom `ListView` `Class` is:

```
public class Trainer extends AppCompatActivity {

    String tabUrl = "http://adoxsolutions.in/numuww/services/trainers";
    private GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    private TrainAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog mprogress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        new Train().execute();

    }

    private class Train extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mprogress = new ProgressDialog(Trainer.this);
            mprogress.setMessage("Loading...");
            mprogress.setIndeterminate(false);
            mprogress.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(tabUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connect.setRequestMethod("POST");

                //               
                System.out.println("Response Code:" + connect.getResponseCode());
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
                String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(response);
                Log.d("VALUE:", response);

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsArray = obj.optJSONArray("Trainers");
                for (int k = 0; k < jsArray.length(); k++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    obj = jsArray.getJSONObject(k);
                    map.put("id", obj.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", obj.getString("name"));
                    map.put("logo", obj.getString("img"));
                    alist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.trainerGrid);
            adapter = new TrainAdapter(getBaseContext(), alist);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mprogress.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.newc, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

class TrainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public TrainAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
        context = c;
        MyArr = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MyArr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trainer_list, null);
        }
            TextView id= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainerId);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainerImage);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainerTexts);
            try {
                image.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(MyArr.get(position).get("logo")));
                text.setText(MyArr.get(position).get("name"));
                id.setText(MyArr.get(position).get("id"));

                if (((position - 9) / 3)  % 9 == 0) {
                    ImageView adimg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainadBanner);
                    adimg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    adimg.getLayoutParams().height=150;
                    adimg.getLayoutParams().width=300;
                    adimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainad);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle h=new Bundle();
                h.putString("id",MyArr.get(position).get("id"));
                Fragment tt1=new TrainerTab1();
                tt1.setArguments(h);

            }
        });

//        }else{
//            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.trainer_list, parent,false);
//            ImageView image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainerImage);
//            TextView text= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainerTexts);
//            try{
//                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
//                text.setText(MyArr.get(position).get("name"));
//                if(position % 9 == 0){
//                    ImageView adimg= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trainadBanner);
//                    adimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainad);
//                }
//
//            } catch(Exception e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        return convertView;
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ERROR";
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;

    private static Bitmap loadBitmap(String tabUrl) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(tabUrl).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            copy(in, out);
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//options.inSampleSize = 1;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + tabUrl);
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
            closeStream(out);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
            out.write(b, 0, read);
        }
    }

}
```

My tab fragment:

```
public class TrainerTab1 extends Fragment {

    String turl="http://adoxsolutions.in/numuww/services/trainer";
    TextView tname,tplace,tsex;

    public TrainerTab1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trainer_tab1, container, false);

           final String tid=getArguments().getString("id");

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        tname= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trainerCourse);
        tplace= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trainerPlace);
        tsex= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trainerSex);
        ImageView photo= (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trainer_photo);
    }
}
```

Comment: after adding the bundle to the fragment, where have you used the fragment transaction to replace/add the fragment?

Comment: you need to replace fragment to change the fragment

`FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentObject);  `

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onClickListener`
after adding the bundle to the fragment.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = Trainer.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.someIDForYourFrameLayout, tt1).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you just ellaborate where to use this exactly. I mean I don't understand how to add id of fragment to transaction.add(**R.id.someIDForYourFrameLayout**, tt1).commit();
I tried like this:

```
 Bundle h=new Bundle();
                h.putString("id",MyArr.get(position).get("id"));
                Fragment tt1=new TrainerTab1();
                tt1.setArguments(h);
                FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transact.add(R.id.trainerFragment,tt1).commit();
```

This is my fragment_trainer_tab_1 layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/trainerFragment"
    tools:context="com.example.anu.numuww.TrainerTab1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/trainer_photo"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/trainers"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trainerCourse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trainerSex"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trainerPlace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/global"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/messenger"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/google_plus"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inst_detail"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/telegram"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/twitter"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inst_instagram"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="About Trainer"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/para"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```